# php, date() not returning the right date/time

Tags: php, date, strtotime

The code below...

```
$date = "02-13-2012";
$start_time = "17:30";
$end_time = "20:00";

$start_timestamp = date("m-d-Y H:i",strtotime($date." ".$start_time));
$end_timestamp = date("m-d-Y H:i",strtotime($date." ".$end_time));

print($start_timestamp);
print($end_timestamp);
```

Returns...

1969-12-31 19:30:00

1969-12-31 20:30:00

Does anyone have any idea why this is not working correctly?

Comment: try this $date = "2012-02-13";

Comment: good question :). I stumbled upon it once in past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this. I think you have to change the date format.

```
$date = "02-13-2012";
$date = str_replace("-","/",$date);
$start_time = "17:30";
$end_time = "20:00";

$start_timestamp = date("m-d-Y H:i",strtotime($date." ".$start_time));
$end_timestamp = date("m-d-Y H:i",strtotime($date." ".$end_time));

print($start_timestamp);
echo "<br/>";
print($end_timestamp);
```

Comment: This worked, all I had to do was replace the `-` with `/` and it worked. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

`02-13-2012 17:30` is not a [recognized date format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php). Either use day-month-year or year-month-day order, or custom parse the date format using, for example, [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Answer (score 0):

your date format is not correct for strtotime function

either change is to

```
 $date = "13-02-2012";
```

or to some other valid format

Answer (score 0):

When you format your date like `xx-yy-zzz`, `strtotime()` interprets it as a date in the normal format, not the American one, so it's `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Comment: @still month-day-year is *obviously not* normal. ;-P

Comment: Well, not normal related to the PHP strtotime parser. :P